# Can't get 960.gs grid container to span full browser height

Tags: html, css, grid, height, 960.gs

I have been working on a project using Compass with the 960.gs plugin. It's worked quite well so far, giving results that look nearly identical across browsers with little effort. I've run into a small problem, however.

The div I am using as 960's main grid container has a vertically tiled background in CSS. I need this background to extend all the way to the bottom of the browser's viewport, but it would seem that 960's use of floats is somehow conflicting with this.

Despite the container's height being set to 100%, the background only extends part of the way down the screen when overflow is unspecified. Setting overflow to hidden fixes it, but hides the scrollbars!

How can this be dealt with? I've used Webkit's inspector look through the code and DOM for problems and as far as I can see there's nothing that should cause this behavior.

It's not online and the code is too large to copy and paste here, but I will recreate the structure in abbreviated psuedocode:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
   <primary background div>
       <960 container div>
           <header div>Stuff</div>
           <main content div>More Stuff</div>
           <footer div></div>
       </div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've scanned the CSS is there is nothing problematic. I'm not floating anything and the most I'm doing is small padding and margins...

Comment: Kinda hard to help if you don't post a link to the site or a sample of the site that shows this.

Comment: Edited to include a bit of code.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell without the actual code, but the prerequisite for block to stretch at `100%` is one of these:

- It's parent have an absolute set height (like `100px` etc.).
- Or *all* parent of this block till `HTML` tag must have `height: 100%`.

So, look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/UvAxV/ — there on frame hover `HTML` and `BODY` get `height: 100%` and the wrapper stretches to `100%` too.

So, in your case, you must to make sure that `HTML`, `BODY` and “primary background div” all have `height: 100%`